# Reference for color sensor

Tags: sensor, rgb, calibration, light-sensor, colour

I am trying to make a colorimeter using TCS3200 sensor and white LED light source.

After weeks of research and understanding on how different white light sources work and what are the algorithms involved in calibrating the sensor in CIE1931 space.

Now I am facing problem in getting a reference for getting a calibration curve.

For example, if I want to map R values, then I also need some reference for which I know R values.

I initially planned to use RAL cards to calibrate my sensor, but the RGB values are not shared on their official website and other websites provide sRGB values and not the actual RGB values.

I even thought of printing varying shade of Red on paper, but I believe there will be a lot of unknown factors in this (printer calibration, RGB space used by the software, etc).

So is there any standard source of known colour against which i can calibrate my sensor?

Edit:
My application is more to sense the change in shade rather than getting the actual color of the subject and that's the reason I was thinking if I can get away with calibrating it against some standard color swatch of known RGB values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't an EE question.

Comment: I understand your point, but can you point me to a right platform where i can ask the same? @Andyaka

Comment: @Mayank: you should make clear what you actually want to achieve. What do you mean by "change in shade"? It is not clear at all what you mean by that. Please make sure (or at least put some effort in) using the correct terms.

Comment: There is no translation between subtractive (RAL, NCS, Pantone) to additive (RGB). For a given light source, light level and gamma curve, you can make an approximation. It's like comparing car engine power to top speed for the entire fleet of cars on our roads. They are related, but there isn't a simple formula or linear relationship.

Comment: @Mayank No, sorry there is no quid pro quo, I can't point you to where you can ask.

Comment: I want to measure the change in color (which will start from white paper and then keep getting red depending upon the glucose content in the liquid dropped on paper; basically a glucometer). So there is a change in only one color which is Red in my case. I want to run POC. I am using red LED in a closed environment to illuminate the paper. I am more interested in knowing that what is the least change in saturation that I can detect.

Comment: This is near an area where I specialize (pyrometry [optics and physics of] and human color perception [far more complex subject, but which requires similar physics and optics as grounding.])  I have two primary questions right now: (1) If you build two of these instruments, do you expect reproducability of results between two different devices? (2) Do you seriously imagine that a red LED can make a "standard candle" source? And one comment: You are planning on using RAL color cards, designed for human color perception problems, for a non-human-related problem (glucose content.)

Comment: (1) Yes, I am expecting reproducibility. (2) I couldn't think of anything else as a monochromatic source which is compact and economical as well. And I have also done some research on off the shelf glucometers and LED source works for them, so I couldn't think of any reason why it shouldn't for me. About RAL, I realised that it's a wrong approach since RAL swatches are made of colored pigments which may not of the color that a human eye perceives.

Comment: @jonk I understand the skepticism for LED but there are number of [sensors](http://ams.com/eng/Products/Spectral-Sensing/Multi-spectral-Sensing/AS7261) in market which actually integrate LED drivers as well in them (for LED to be used as light source), I understand that LED is not an ideal source of light but I believe its a engineering choice of what can work best for us.

Comment: @Mayank Reproducibility places some significant burdens here. LEDs are NOT even close to monochromatic -- but you know that. Also, I worked on using LEDs as standard candles. I had to heat them up and hold at a constant temp. But only after a 48 hour bake-in period, which found and eliminated about 99.4% of them. Only a few settle down enough to worthwhile. Most just flitter around. And this is with 0.1% precision current sources. People wrongly seem to imagine that if the current is controlled well, the LED emits consistently. Nope! "Not ideal" is an understatement.

Comment: @Mayank There are a number of other issues that are coming to mind, but this would turn into a long discussion here that would be deep-6'd in a moment by an active moderator here. Suffice it that I believe there isn't as simple an answer here as you imagine. I think I'd enjoy learning from you about your situation and goals and perhaps being able to help a little bit -- it sounds like fun -- but this isn't the setting.

Comment: @jonk thank you for all your input. Sure it sounds like fun, and probably I can learn a lot from you. Probably I am asking for too much but can you start a chat with me(since I don't have the reputation) or any other setting in which I can get in touch with you.

Comment: @Mayank My email is at the bottom of this page, for example: http://www.infinitefactors.org/jonk/patch.html

Answer (score 2):

You need a light source with a spectrum of known power vs. color (i.e. frequency or wavelength) distribution.

(As much as I understand your problem you don't need absolute intensities (e.g. Watt/Steradian) but just relative intensities with respect to color).

There come two relatively simple sources to mind:

- black body radiation (e.g. of a incandescent light bulb) whose spectral distribution is directly known by a physical law, [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) (you need to know the temperature of the filament)
- sunlight (after passing through the atmoshphere till e.g. sea level) whose spectral distribution is empirically known (well measured) and you have a high chance of finding published spectral distribution data.

Comment: That sounds too much of work the project I am looking for. I am looking to measure the change in color intensity hence I believe I might be able to get away without the complexity mentioned above.

Comment: @Mayank: you should make clear what you actually want to achieve. What do you mean by "color intensisty"? Do you mean saturation ("colorfulness"). Please make sure (or at least put some effort in) using the correct terms.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, even I am struggling with a lot of names and trying to make sense of it. And yes I mean saturation.

Answer (score 1):

long story short: for calibration, you're right, you'll need *known* quantities. In case of colorimeters, that is something of known color illuminated with light of a known color temperature (and usually, also a known intensity). That's a bit of an expensive test setup you're aiming for, if you need to build it yourself (these lamps don't come cheap).

Why not simply buy a sufficiently calibrated colorimeter, or a colorimeter calibration toolkit, and calibrate your device against the readings / known values of the commercial one? Seems both the cheapest and easiest approach.

Comment: Actually, my application is more to sense the change in shade rather than getting the actual color of the subject and that's the reason I was thinking if I can get away with calibrating it against some standard color swatch of known RGB values. purchasing colorimeter calibration toolkit seems to be an ideal option given the cost and complexity, though if there is any alternative then please guide with the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in matching colors you don't need to calibrate. A stable colorimeter will give find differences in color which might, in themselves, be inaccurate, but will show color differences. Your reference should be the sample you're trying to match. The only problem is that you can't match using two different colorimeters.